# Using MVC3 AJAX call to ActionResults fails when returning a File

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action result that returns a created File object (simplified for display!):

```
public ActionResult Create(int recID, int templateID)
{
    //Get dbRecord from recID
    DBRecord dbRecord = db.dbRecord.Find(recID);

    //Get Template from templateID
    Template template = db.Templates.Find(templateID);
    if (template == null) throw new FileLoadException(string.Format("No database record found for template reference {0}",templateID));

    //set fileOutput details
    WordFile fileOutput = new WordFile(dbRecord, Server.MapPath("~/Documents/"),template);

    //Create XML object for Template
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

    //Save resulting document
    xDoc.InnerXml = mergeData(template,dbRecord);
    xDoc.Save(fileOutput.fullName);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileOutput.fullName)) throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("File {0} could not be created", fileOutput.fileName));

    //Return saved document
    return File(fileOutput.fullName, "application/doc", fileOutput.fileName);
}
```

If I call this via an HTML RouteLink

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("Generate via HTML
        , "GenerateDocument"
        , new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { 
                    controller = "Template"
                    , action = "Create"
                    , recID = 1
                    ,templateID = 1
                }
            )
        )%>
```

**Edit 1:** It works fine, the document is generated and the user is prompted to open, save, etc. However, if I call it via an AJAX RouteLink, the code steps through, the document is created on the server, but the user is not prompted to open or save.

```
<%: Ajax.RouteLink("Generate via AJAX"
        , "GenerateDocument"
        , new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { 
                    controller = "Template"
                    , action = "Create"
                    , recID = 1
                    , templateID = 1 }
            )
        , new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod="POST"
                , LoadingElementId="Refresh"
            })%>
```

Is there an inherent restriction that prevents AJAX returning a file type or have I missed the right search combination to find an obvious answer?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "if I call it via an AJAX RouteLink, it fails"? How does it fail?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that is a bit vague...  It hits ActionResult, steps through the code and does not return the generated document.
When the Html version ends, it prompts the user to open or save the document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about.  Are you trying to return the file contents to a javascript variable?  That is the only thing I can imagine an "AJAX RouteLink" would be good for.  If you want it to prompt the user to open or save, use a normal link.  If you're trying to embed the file in the page, don't return the file, return the html that you would use to do the embedding.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the following.
*User clicks 'Generate document' link
*Action result gets called.  While code is executing, a potentially lengthy process for large documents, the user has a progress indicator.
*Document generated and user is prompted to Open/Save/etc.

Users are renowned for impatience and I'd like to use the AJAX.LoadingElementId to keep them informed at step 2.

If an AJAX call can only return a text value rather than a file result, would it be possible to use an onSuccess function to then call a separate ActionResult passing the url of the created document?